# How to get current location using CLLocationManager in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I can already find the current location using latitude and longitude, but I would also like to be able to find the current location given a zip code.

Here is what I have so far:

**.h**

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

{

CLLocationManager *locationManager;
 CLLocation *currentLocation;

    IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *lable2;

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *myMapview;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lable1;
@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];



    locationManager.delegate = self;


    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;


    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;


    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


    _myMapview.showsUserLocation = YES;

    [self->locationManager startUpdatingLocation];



    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];


    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];


    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];

    //NSLog(@”dLatitude : %@”, latitude);
    //NSLog(@”dLongitude : %@”,longitude);
    NSLog(@"MY HOME :%@", latitude);
    NSLog(@"MY HOME: %@ ", longitude);

}

#pragma mark CLLocationManager Delegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    [self->locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];




    NSLog(@"my latitude :%f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude);

    NSLog(@"my longitude :%f",currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    lable2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];


    NSLog(@"Detected Location : %f, %f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
                       if (error)
                       {
                           NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                           return;
                       }

NSLog(@"Monday");
                       CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                       NSLog(@"placemark.ISOcountryCode %@",placemark.ISOcountryCode);

                   }];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil)
    {

    label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    lable2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Your phrasing is confusing. You say you want to find the user's "current" location based on zip code. However, if you specify an arbitrary zip code then you don't want the user's CURRENT location, you want to calculate a location for a zip code. Those are different things.

Answer (score 22):

**Step 1:** Import `MobileCoreServices` framework in `.h` File

`#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>`

**Step 2:** Add delegate `CLLocationManagerDelegate`

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLLocation *currentLocation;
}
```

**Step 3:** Add this code in class file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self CurrentLocationIdentifier]; // call this method
}
```

**Step 4:** Method to get location

```
//------------ Current Location Address-----
-(void)CurrentLocationIdentifier
{
    //---- For getting current gps location
    locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    //------
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!(error))
         {
             CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"\nCurrent Location Detected\n");
             NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
             NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
             NSString *Address = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:locatedAt];
             NSString *Area = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:placemark.locality];
             NSString *Country = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:placemark.country];
             NSString *CountryArea = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", Area,Country];
             NSLog(@"%@",CountryArea);
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error %@", error);
             NSLog(@"\nCurrent Location Not Detected\n");
             //return;
             CountryArea = NULL;
         }
         /*---- For more results 
         placemark.region);
         placemark.country);
         placemark.locality); 
         placemark.name);
         placemark.ocean);
         placemark.postalCode);
         placemark.subLocality);
         placemark.location);
          ------*/
     }];
}
```

Comment: Your post is a good explanation of how to figure out the zip code of the user's current location. However, the user is asking for the opposite - how to find a location based on a zip code. That requires forward geocoding, not reverse geocoding.

Comment: @SVM-RAjESH thk for answered i will try

Comment: @DuncanC : User tried to get address from current location. But title only asked to get from zip code.

Comment: @Duncan C get some location using Zip code is possible or NOT

Comment: @SVM-RAJESH, Why do you need to import MobileCoreServices?

Comment: Note that placemark locality can be nil in unincorporated areas. This can crash creating a string with this value.

Comment: @PavanAlapati, yes it is possible to get a location using only a zip code. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: whats #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h> is for. for cllocationmanager you need  cllocation framework. in reversegeocode function, you should enumerate each placemark object, not only first object.

Comment: @Duncan C yes i want get a location using a Zip code if u have code plz upload that code thanks in advanced

Comment: @PavanAlapati, you want to use the CLGeocoder method geocodeAddressString. See if you can figure it out without me spoon-feeding you code.

Answer (score 6):

**Here is a code to get user current location using block**

1) `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>`

2) `<CLLocationManagerDelegate>`

3) in .h file

```
//Location
typedef void(^locationBlock)();

//Location
-(void)GetCurrentLocation_WithBlock:(void(^)())block;

@property (nonatomic, strong) locationBlock _locationBlock;
@property (nonatomic,copy)CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic)CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *current_Lat;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *current_Long;
```

4) in .m file

```
#pragma mark - CLLocationManager
-(void)GetCurrentLocation_WithBlock:(void(^)())block {
    self._locationBlock = block;
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [_locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [_locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [_locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
            [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }
    }
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *currentLoc=[locations objectAtIndex:0];
    _coordinate=currentLoc.coordinate;
    _current_Lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",currentLoc.coordinate.latitude];
    _current_Long = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",currentLoc.coordinate.longitude];
    NSLog(@"here lat %@ and here long %@",_current_Lat,_current_Long);
    self._locationBlock();
    [_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    _locationManager = nil;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
}
```

5) Call function

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self GetCurrentLocation_WithBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Lat ::%f,Long ::%f",[self.current_Lat floatValue],[self.current_Long floatValue]);
    }];
}
```

6) And add below line to .plist

**Any one or both of below keys needs to be added in Info.plist file.**

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call [Google APIs Maps](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=36521&sensor=true) service to get the location using zipcode:

Just enter your zipcode in `address={your zipcode}`.

Comment: my code   displayed  only in Console  but not in map that is Simulator

Comment: off course you have to display that location in the map yourself.

Comment: k but longitude and latitude data Double type but i don't no how to pass NSDictionsary  values into Double Variable

Comment: First you have to parse the whole JSON response and get the values from that.

Comment: if you adder stand my code and then plz find that solution 7 location display on MAP

Comment: @ahay are you get my code or Not if you adder stand my code and then plz find that solution 7 location display on MAP

Comment: 7 location display? I am not getting you.

Answer (score 0):

if location permissions not asking when you first launch then you cant get your current location .

iOS8 has got us major API changes with the LocationsServices

Assuming [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] return YES,

With the First Launch of the iOS App [both iOS7 and iOS8] - locationMangers(CLLocationManager)