# IOS Map user location not displayed

Tags: mapkit

I am experimenting with apple mapkit [apple mapkit guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW1), and i noticed that to show the user location (blue dot), it suffice to set show userlocation to true in storyboard. I am testing on simulator (trying iphone 6 and 7) and i emulate locations using gpx files.

My problem is no blue dot appears on screen. What can be wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current location using CLLocationManager in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554127/how-to-get-current-location-using-cllocationmanager-in-ios)

Comment: I am using the mapview itslelf, wish has its own locationmanager. As i understand it should handle the location updates and display of current location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you actually starting up the location manager and updating the location?

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

And don't forget to ask the user for permission as well.

Comment: it appears asking permissions and showing the location are 2 different things. so one should show location on map in case permission given.